# I cannot create Window

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to create window already for several days, but always it tells me "Cannot create window"
When it randomly creates window, CPU goes 50%. Can you help me and tell what causes that error?
Here is source code:

```
#include<Windows.h> 
int AppRunning=1;
void TellError(LPCWSTR error,HWND hWnd=NULL);
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wparam,LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(msg){
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            AppRunning=0;
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wparam,lparam);
}

HWND NewWindow(LPCTSTR title,int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wcex.hIcon = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor = NULL;
    wcex.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"Svet-ver1.0";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION); 
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)){
        TellError(L"Cannot register window!");
        return NULL;
    }
    return CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, L"Svet3D-ver1.0", title, WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE, xpos, ypos, width, height, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
 }

 int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE hPrevInst,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
 {
    MSG msg;
    HWND hWnd = NewWindow(L"Svet",100,100,500,500); 
    if(!hWnd){
        TellError(L"Cannot create window!");
        return 0;
    }
    while(AppRunning){
        if(PeekMessage(&msg,hWnd,0,0,PM_REMOVE)){
            if(!IsDialogMessage(hWnd,&msg)){
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
    }
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    return 0;
 }
 void TellError(LPCWSTR error,HWND hWnd){
     MessageBox(hWnd,error,NULL,MB_OK);
 }
```

Comment: And you have dual CPU machine, right?

Comment: PeekMessage does not wait for messages and exits immediately, you call it once again then and you end up in an infinite loop consuming 100% on one of the two of your CPUs/cores.

Comment: Thanks :) I used GetMessage ,now, it uses 0-5% CPU

Comment: When a call to `CreateWindowEx` fails, call `GetLastError` to find out why. Windows has a mechanism to inform you why API calls fails. Please take time to learn how to use it. Doing so will save time in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class name passed to `RegisterClassEx` is `"Svet-ver1.0"`, but when creating the window you are using a different class name `"Svet3D-ver1.0"`.

Also you are using `PeekMessage` in the main loop and this will just loop quickly when there are no messages in the queue. This empty loop is what is burning all your CPU (50% is probably because you've a dual core system).

You should use `GetMessage` instead, that will wait for next message without wasting CPU time.